# Should I install Nagios on the pfsense?

Tags: nagios, pfsense

I'm planning to install Nagios, but I'm not sure if there is a package for pfsense, or can I install separated from pfsense but on the same machine?

Anyone had experience with that?

Second part of my question is, where should I put Nagios, since I'm running one machine where I have installed pfsense, behind this same machine is running server which is in the DMZ zone.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not do this.

Let your router be a router and install nagios elsewhere. Installing extra, non-stock software on an appliance not only decreases the security of the platform, but also introduces many complexities in performing upgrades.

Comment: Sure, why not? That would be a much better solution than installing on your router.

Comment: That's far too broad of a question to answer. You need to learn what is required and then sort out the configs. There is no reason they can't all co-exist though.